# Understanding Unix process substitution behavior

Tags: unix

```
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' <(ls)  # output:   /dev/fd/4 file
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' < <(ls) # output:   - file
```

In the above one-liners, the first one generates file descriptor and then the filename where as the second one generates the hypen (-) character and then the filename. Why this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can see it this way:

```
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' <(ls)
# is the same as
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' output_of_ls_command
```

`awk` will read a tmp file (created by `bash`, let's name it as `output_of_ls_command`(it's `/dev/fd/4` in your case))

---

```
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' < <(ls)
# is the same as
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' < output_of_ls_command
```

`awk` will read stdin (`bash` read the tmp file, and send the content to `awk`, `FILENAME` is `-`)